# How do I publish an App to a machine without IIS installed?

Tags: visual-studio, publish, visual-web-developer

I'm trying to publish a web app from Visual Studio, but I don't have IIS installed on my desktop.

I can publish it on the same machine which I'm running the Visual Studio and all machines in the same LAN must access this web page.

I've already tried to follow the steps of the link below, but it doesn't works.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Try the file system option.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy a website to the target location by simply working in Explorer and selecting the files/directories needed and opening up a external location via drag and drop in the file system.